# ggplot create graph representing date ranges using start and end dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a graph showing a bar indicating the length of time data was collected for each site. In the following data frame, I have a column for the start time (`log.start`) and end time (`log.end`) for each `site`. I would like to have one graph, with date on the x axis and site on the y axis.

```
df <- structure(list(site = c("APIS01", "APIS02", "APIS03", "APIS04", 
"APIS05", "APIS06", "APIS07", "APIS08", "APIS10", "APIS11"), 
    log.start = structure(c(17622, 17622, 17655, 17655, 17655, 
    17655, 17655, 17655, 17655, 17655), class = "Date"), log.end = structure(c(17780, 
    17756, 17785, 17784, 17784, 17784, 17756, 17784, 17785, 17713
    ), class = "Date"), park = c("APIS", "APIS", "APIS", "APIS", 
    "APIS", "APIS", "APIS", "APIS", "APIS", "APIS")), .Names = c("site", 
"log.start", "log.end", "park"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a geom_segment here pretty easily

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(y=site)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=log.start, xend=log.end, y=site, yend=site), size=5)
```

[image]